# Delayed Job inserts every request twice into the backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job

I have an Rails 5 Application wherein it makes use of Delayed Job to fetch data from an external API and save it on a DB store,

However, when I place a request for the seeding to be done from the API, it queues in the same seed request twice instead of treating it once.

Upon initial observation, I do see that the handlers for the two records are quite different from the other. Posted below are snippets of my code that i have tried.

Need to understand as to why this could be happening. Any help sought would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Controller Code

```
class MovieController < ApplicationController

  def new_movie_seed_request
    @languages = Language.all.by_lang_name
    @movie = Movie.new
  end

  def seed_request_for_movie
    @movie_title = params["mov_title"]
    @movie_language = params["mov_language"]
    if params.present? && params["mov_title"].present? && params["mov_language"].present?
      Delayed::Job.enqueue SeedMovieViaTmdbJob.new(params["mov_title"], params["mov_language"])
      flash.now[:success] = 'Request for seeding has been submitted successfully'
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Please enter valid movie title and movie language in order to proceed with the seeding request'
      redirect_to action: "new_movie_seed_request"
    end
  end

end
```

Delayed Job Table Records After enqueuing the request.

```
INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("handler", "run_at", "queue", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["handler", "--- !ruby/object:ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper\njob_data:\n  job_class: SeedMovieViaTmdbJob\n  job_id: b21ae8e7-65ec-4960-b697-d6f056c275da\n  provider_job_id: \n  queue_name: default\n  priority: 0\n  arguments:\n  - Gully Boy\n  - hi\n  executions: 0\n  locale: en\n"], ["run_at", "2019-03-22 09:20:41.852410"], ["queue", "default"], ["created_at", "2019-03-22 09:20:41.852566"], ["updated_at", "2019-03-22 09:20:41.852566"]]

INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("handler", "run_at", "queue", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["handler", "--- !ruby/object:SeedMovieViaTmdbJob\narguments:\n- Gully Boy\n- hi\njob_id: b21ae8e7-65ec-4960-b697-d6f056c275da\nqueue_name: default\npriority: \nexecutions: 0\n"], ["run_at", "2019-03-22 09:20:41.877060"], ["queue", "default"], ["created_at", "2019-03-22 09:20:41.877122"], ["updated_at", "2019-03-22 09:20:41.877122"]]
```

Notice the change in the handler attributes of the two records that have been created.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a code responsible for queuing new job in `SeedMovieViaTmdbJob`?

Comment: @MrShemek I am queuing them inside the controller itself.

Comment: Yes, but what if you are queueing job that queues itself? I am sometimes using it.

Comment: @MrShemek sorry for i am not able to follow you on what you are trying to say. Could you be a bit more elaborate please?

Comment: can you please update your question with the code of `SeedMovieViaTmdbJob`? Just the `initialize` method.

Comment: @MrShemek I dont have an initlaize method in the job file, but i do have the perform method which has the logic pertaining to seed data from the external API Source. Is that you are asking for?

Answer (score 2):

Aha!

Hooks: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks

Delayed::Job has an enqueue hook that calls the `enqueue` method on your Job class when it is enqueued.  If your job happens to be an ActiveJob, this will trigger the enqueue method defined by the ActiveJob::Base class, which actually queues the job again! (This time as an activejob)

Solution: If you're creating a custom job that you're going to enqueue by calling Delayed::Job.enqueue, don't inherit from ActiveJob!  Just use a plain old Ruby object with a `perform` method.  (Alternately, you could override the `enqueue` method with one that does nothing, but there's no need to inherit from ActiveJob in the first place really)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. ***Do not*** inherit the job from `ActiveJob::Base` and trigger it with:

   `Delayed::Job.enqueue SomeJob.new(args)`

**or**

2. ***Do*** inherit the job from `ActiveJob::Base` and trigger it with:

   `SomeJob.perform_later(args)`

(But when inheriting from `ActiveJob::Base` **and** using `Delayed::Job.enqueue` at the same time, it will trigger the job twice, as explained by mltsy).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the job inheriting from `ActiveJob::Base`, you can enqueue it with Active Job's syntax like so:

`MyJob.new(params).enqueue`

instead of:

`Delayed::Job.enqueue Myjob.new(params)`

This will only enqueue it once and it will still be processed by Delayed::Job